# Add third part self signed certificate in JBoss EAP

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, java-8, keystore, jboss-eap-7

I am developing an application using Spring Boot that calls another application (say application A) over HTTPS and deploying the application as war file in JBoss EAP 7.2. Until recently, application a was using a certificate issued by a trusted authority and my application was able to access the application without any change in JBoss or the VM in which JBoss is installed. Recently application A changed the certificate on their side and is now using a self signed certificate say xyz.crt. So I am now getting an exception while trying to connect to application a because my application does not trust the certificate. Can anyone please guide me how to add the self signed certificate file xyz.crt to JBoss or Java so that my application recognizes the certificate and I am able to call aplication A over HTTPS?